# What is the difference in assigning a processed value directly to a variable and assigning without processing and then processed using && operator

Tags: javascript

I saw a function that receives a string parameter then performs some operations with it; like this:

```
const val = this.searchParam && this.searchParam.trim().toLowerCase();
```

My question is, why don't assign directly the processed string? Like this:

```
const val = this.searchParam.trim().toLowerCase();
```

I tried this in JS Bin to see if there's a difference, and the result is the same.

What do they exactly use the && operator?

Comment: Did you try it with `this.searchParam` being `null` or `undefined`?

Comment: The code expects that `this.searchParam` *may* be falsey and prevents an error to be thrown in this case.

Comment: the "duplicate" doesn't directly answers the question, but to answer it, its because in case this.searchParams is null or undefined (other falsy values), it will throw the classic `cannot call <function name> of null` or `cannot call <function name> of undefined`, with `&&` it ensures that it will only trigger the function calls if the searchParam is not falsy

Comment: its the sortcut of `if (this.searchParam) val = this.searchParam.trim().toLowerCase();`

Comment: @IamL That's missing an `else val = this.searchParam`…

Comment: @deceze not if its the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code snippet below, the first log writes `undefined`, the second throws an error:

```js
searchParam = undefined

console.log(searchParam && searchParam.trim().toLowerCase());
console.log(searchParam.trim().toLowerCase());
```

Therefore, the result is **not** the same